# Why do tensorflow Variables in outputs of dynamic (or static) rnn with lstm cell has plus-one dimensionality?

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

My question is about the elemental dynamic or static rnn outputs's dimensionality.

```
nlu_input = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[4,1607,1])
cell = tf.nn.rnn_cell.BasicLSTMCell(80)
outts, states = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(cell=cell, inputs=nlu_input, dtype=tf.float32)
```

Then tf.gloabal_valiables() returns the following list.

`[<tf.Variable 'rnn/basic_lstm_cell/kernel:0' shape=(81, 320) dtype=float32_ref>,<tf.Variable 'rnn/basic_lstm_cell/bias:0' shape=(320,) dtype=float32_ref>]`

I expected the tf.Variable 'rnn/basic_lstm_cell/kernel:0' shape=(80, 320), because 320 = 4*80 and the unit number is 80.

> Why the dimensionality of the kernel is incremented?

Answer (score 0):

According to the tensorflow implementation: [BasicLSTMCell source code](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/ops/rnn_cell_impl.py#L543). The shape of `kernel` is `[input_depth + h_depth, 4 * num_units]`, which `input_depth` is your input vector dimension, and `h_depth` is your hidden units count. So your kernel shape is `[1 + 80, 4 * 80]`.